# im getting a syntax error when i run my shell script, the error is in my for each loop and says unespected token `;;'

Tags: bash, shell

Im trying to make a shell script that searches for sketchy processes, prints out a list of the pid and name of the process, asks you if you would like to kill them and then if you say yes goes through and kills each process.
here is my code so far

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "CyPat Script by Valaire"
echo "  ~scetchy processes~"

$var  ps -aux | grep -e test -e idk | awk '{print $2 "  " $11}'

IFS=' '
read -a NAMES <<< "$var"
echo ${NAMES}

read -p "Kill all? " yn
case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) for name in $names
        do
            kill -9 $name; break;;
        [Nn]* ) echo no; break;;
        *) echo "y or n";;
esac
```

Comment: You're missing `done` at the end of the `for` loop.

Comment: Why do you have an unconditional `break` in your loop? It will stop the loop after killing the first `$name`.

Comment: You assign the variable `NAMES` but then use `$names`.

Comment: Why do you need a loop at all? Just do `kill -9 "${NAMES[@]}"`.

Comment: now i get an error on line 14 saying: arguments must be process or job IDs

Comment: Your *main* problem is that you don't appear to know how to spell your own name :-)

Comment: lol paxdiablo believe it or not that actually is how us spell my name edit- yup i spelled my own name wrong

Comment: So `Valarie Braga` is spelled wrong?

Comment: lol wow im smart i did indeed spell my own name wrong

Comment: Shellcheck produces [5 findings](https://pastebin.com/yiBSSGi3) for your code. You should fix them before continuing.

Comment: @ValarieBrega do NOT delete content from your original question through editing. You are free to ADD information below your original, but do not delete original content. Why? When you delete content, it renders all comments and answers referring to the deleted content irrelevant. Where is the `for` loop referred to in comment No. 1?

Answer (score 2):

```
$var  ps -aux | grep -e test -e idk | awk '{print $2 "  " $11}'
```

is not the correct way to assign a variable with the output of a command. It should be

```
var=$(ps -aux | grep -e test -e idk | awk '{print $2 "  " $11}')
```

There's also no need to use `grep` when using `awk`, since it can do its own pattern matching.

```
var=$(ps -aux | awk '/test|idk/ {print $2 "  " $11}')
```

You need to add `done` to your `for` loop, and loop over the correct variable. You also shouldn't break out of the loop.

```
for name in "${NAMES[@]}"; do
    kill -9 "$name"
done ;;
```

But your `$NAMES` array contains alternating PIDs and commands, you should only pass the PIDs to `kill`. So the loop should be:

```
for ((i=0; i < ${#NAMES[@]}; i+=2)); do
    kill -9 "${NAMES[i]}"
done
```

You shouldn't have `break` in the `[Nn]*)` case. You can only use `break` inside a loop.

The corrected script should be:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "CyPat Script by Valaire"
echo "  ~scetchy processes~"

var=$(ps -aux | awk '/test|idk/ {print $2 "  " $11}')

IFS=' '
NAMES=($var)
echo "${NAMES[@]}"

read -p "Kill all? " yn
case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) 
            for ((i=0; i < ${#NAMES[@]}; i+=2)); do
                kill -9 "${NAMES[i]}"
            done;;
        [Nn]* ) echo no;;
        *) echo "y or n";;
esac
```

It's also not a good idea to give your variable all-uppercase names. These are conventionally reserved for environment variables, and your variable might clash.

Comment: hey, thank ya im getting a new error now tho. line 16: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
line 19: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo and left out the `}` in `${NAMES[@]}`

Comment: sorry to keep asking dumb questions but i have another error. line 14: kill: /usr/sbin/apache2: arguments must be process or job IDs

Comment: The arguments to `kill` have to be just the PIDs. You have both PIDs and commands in `$NAMES`.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to call `kill` with just the PIDs.

Comment: I think your code needs to use `read -a NAMES <<< $var`  or else you'll only ever get one process in the array

Comment: sorry, I'm wrong. You just get one process regardless.

Comment: I've changed it to the simpler `NAMES=($var)`

Comment: Yes, that's simpler. I think the `IFS=' '` is redundant now.